# Ignore certain ViewModel properties in API requests?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have the following example Resource Model defined for API Create/Read/Update/Delete interactions involving the **Customer** types:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Url]
    public Uri Website { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset WhenCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset WhenUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

**Id**, **WhenCreated**, and **WhenUpdated** are metadata to be generated by the underlying data repository and as such, if the customer adds them to a request they should not be kept (Id for example, would be specified in the URL so no need to include in the request body). However, these values are still important to the client.

**Is there a simple approach to ignoring these metadata attributes if sent in the client request?** I would expect this in the form of an attribute but have not found anything promising for .NET Core 3.1.

The **JsonIgnore** attribute would make sense but it wouldn't serialize the values in responses either.

I could create a separate model only used by clients for requests but this seems redundant, especially because it will require new mapping profiles. However, if using something like Swashbuckle for API documentation this could be the best approach since the class documentation wouldn't represent those as valid properties for requests.

I could add some logic to remove those properties in the business logic layer but that would likely involve another request to the database to retrieve their original values so it isn't ideal.

Thank you!

Comment: `JsonIgnoreAttribute` works for 2 directions, so if you want 1 direction only (serialization to response), you of course need custom json converter. However I'm still not sure about your scenario, usually we have just one complex model bound from the whole request body, ***cannot*** mix them with other kinds of model binding (to that same complex view model) like from query string. So you seem to be able to bind your view model from ***both*** request body ***and*** query string, which must be done with some custom model binding. Could you post more code involving that?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear: I'm not binding from the query string. If I have a `CustomerController` class which exclusively uses the `CustomerModel` for requests and responses, I need a way to avoid clients changing the `Id` property. `Id` is perfectly necessary to provide in the response payload, but I don't want it to be honored if provided in, say, a `PUT` or `PATCH` operation.

Comment: if so you can take a look at the `BindAttribute` (for opt-in) and `BindNeverAttribute` (for opt-out). That's of course used at the design time, not for dynamic scenario. If you want something dynamic, we may have to use some custom convention to apply those attributes to the parameter models at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Is that also a two-way binding though (e.g. if `BindNever` is applied, does that also mean the value is ignored when responding to a request?)

Comment: No, `BindNever` is applied on the ***parameters*** of your controller action, it affects the input request only, not for response.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, and looks like it works as expected. Thanks so much! With respect to design... is that approach common, or is it more common and/or sensible in my scenario to have separate models for Request and Response? It seems like unnecessary extra work to duplicate most of the properties and mappings (even via inheritance).

Comment: The `Bind` and `BindNever` are used originally for protecting against over-posting (some kind of security-related). But I think it's suitable for your scenario as long as you don't want to duplicate your view models. View model inheriting is also a good approach if you design it well. I would adapt both solutions if possible although personally I will try to not use `Bind` and `BindNever` attributes to keep the controller actions look as clean as possible.

Comment: Think CQRS way and your problem will solve!